# What did John mean in Mathew 3:10 the axe is laid on to the root of trees?

Tags: jesus, new-testament, john-the-baptist

> ***Mathew 3:10*** And now also **the axe is laid unto the root of the trees**: therefore every tree which bringeth not forth good fruit is hewn down, and cast into the fire.

What was John referring to as the root of the trees? It seems to be a single root but out of it are many trees. How do you understand this verse?

Comment: An astute comment regarding the singular root and the plural trees. (Up-voted +1.) My mind cannot avoid being prompted in the direction of 'I am the vine, ye are the branches' and the consequence of not abiding in the vine.

Comment: **Coming Judgment** John is announcing the same thing Jesus warned the women of, when He was being led away to be crucified: The Destruction of Jerusalem! *Daughters of Jerusalem, do not weep for me; weep for yourselves and your children.* (Luke 23:28) The sins of the Israelites were so egregious, the nation had to be destroyed. (Matthew 23) *Look, your House is left to you desolate.*

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is in the previous three verses, Matt 3:7-9 of which V10 is the summary and conclusion:

> **7** But when John saw many of the Pharisees and Sadducees coming to his place of baptism, he said to them, “You brood of vipers, who
> warned you to flee from the coming wrath? **8** Produce fruit, then,
> in keeping with repentance. **9** And do not presume to say to
> yourselves, ‘We have Abraham as our father.’ For I tell you that out
> of these stones God can raise up children for Abraham.

Thus, John the Baptist was warning the Jewish leadership, Pharisees and Sadducees, against their theological and spiritual arrogance and surly superiority.  Then he bluntly warns them that just because they were the chosen people does not guarantee their salvation - God could raise up others in their place if needed!!

He then concludes using a common idiom of a tree symbolizing people:

> The axe lies ready at the root of the trees, and every tree that does
> not produce good fruit will be cut down and thrown into the fire.

That is, God has the axe raised and ready to cut down the chosen people and raise up others for the task unless you repent and "produce works in keeping with repentance".

Ellicott offers these comments:

> The ax is laid unto the root of the trees.—The symbolism which saw in
> “trees” the representatives of human characters, of nations, and
> institutions, had been recognised in Isaiah’s parable of the vine
> (Isaiah 5:1-7), in Jeremiah’s of the vine and the olive (Jeremiah
> 2:21; Jeremiah 11:16), and the Baptist’s application of it was but a
> natural extension. Judgments that were only partial or corrective were
> as the pruning of the branches (John 15:2). Now the axe was laid to
> the root, and the alternative was preservation or destruction. For the
> unfruitful tree there was the doom of fire.

This is a very sobering thing.  Jesus said something very similar later in His ministry in Matt 21:43 -

> "Therefore I tell you that the kingdom of God will be taken away from
> you and given to a people who will produce its fruit.

Again, we have the same idea in Matt 23:37, 38 -

> O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, who kills the prophets and stones those sent
> to her, how often I have longed to gather your children together, as a
> hen gathers her chicks under her wings, but you were unwilling! Look,
> your house is left to you desolate.

Jesus like the metaphor of the plants symbolizing people as He uses it again, with the same idea in the parable of the vine as per John 15:1-8.  Note V2 -

> He cuts off every branch in Me that bears no fruit, and every branch
> that does bear fruit, He prunes to make it even more fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

> Matthew 3:7 But when he saw many of the **Pharisees** and **Sadducees** coming to where he was baptizing, he said to them: “You brood of vipers! Who warned you to flee from the coming wrath? 8 Produce **fruit** in keeping with repentance. 9And do not think you can say to yourselves, ‘We have Abraham as our father.’ I tell you that out of these stones God can raise up children for Abraham. 10The ax is already at the **root** of the **trees**, and every tree that does not produce good fruit will be cut down and thrown into the fire.

This is how I imagine the symbolism. It is not about pruning.
The trees symbolize people and institutions, such as the Pharisees and Sadducees. The singular root binds and places in the same boat everyone that does not produce good fruit. John the Baptizer is talking about the wholesale destruction of bad characters.
E.g., the Sadducee institution has completely disappeared and been replaced by other children of Abraham which now include the gentiles. The unfruitful are doomed to the fire.

> Hebrews 6:8
> But land that produces thorns and thistles is worthless and is in danger of being cursed. In the end it will be **burned**.

What did John mean in Mathew 3:10 the axe is laid on to the root of trees?

The axe aims at the singular root for the wholesale destruction of unfruitful people.

Answer (score 0):

I believe regardless of your upbringing, repented believers have been given the power to put the ax to the root, by the power of God, of the evil in their lives to cut it off and have it no longer bear its evil fruit in your generation or your children’s.  YOU have the choice to end it!  The ax represents the word of God, and the root is the evil, the stronghold in one’s life.  The tree represents the people and things that have been nurtured to grow long before you got here and because no one cut it down (denounced the evil- the addiction, molestation, abusive behavior) it continued to produce and has affected your life and that of your children, grandchildren, and will continue to do so until someone recognizes this stronghold they are living under. Whatever was your past or your parents struggles, does not have to be yours.
Rewrite the script and end generational bondage.  The enemy does not want you to be aware that you know how to do this.  Use the word of God and cut it down!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Some useful answers are provided here. Our best thinking is that John as the forerunner he was to Christ was speaking for all who get stuck in claiming to be planted and abiding in the Tree of Life, our Lord Jesus Christ, yet are not producing the fruit of the Spirit Galatians 5:22-23.

Yes, certainly Matthew is exposing the 'brood of vipers', those of whom our Lord Jesus the Anointed and Anointing One would also testify that "Abraham is not your Father otherwise you would come to me. But you are the children of your father the devil (John 8:31-47). Very, very sobering words to speak to His own to whom He came and who received Him not.

> <sup>**9**</sup> The true light that gives light to everyone was coming into the world. <sup>**10**</sup> He was in the world, and though the world was made through him, the world did not recognize him. <sup>**11**</sup> He came to that which was his own, but his own did not receive him. <sup>**12**</sup> Yet to all who did receive him, to those who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of God— <sup>**13**</sup> children born not of natural descent, nor of human decision or a husband’s will, but born of God.
>
> <sup>**14**</sup> The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us. We have seen his glory, the glory of the one and only Son, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth. (John 1:9-14)

John the brother of James, both sons of Zebedee, and Gospel writer had been a disciple of John the Baptist until John instructed Him to behold the Lamb of God that takes away the sins of the world.

> <sup>**35**</sup> The next day John was there again with two of his disciples. <sup>**36**</sup> When he saw Jesus passing by, he said, “Look, the Lamb of God!”
>
> <sup>**37**</sup> When the two disciples heard him say this, they followed Jesus. <sup>**38**</sup> Turning around, Jesus saw them following and asked, “What do you want?”
>
> They said, “Rabbi” (which means “Teacher”), “where are you staying?”
>
> <sup>**39**</sup> “Come,” he replied, “and you will see.”
>
> So they went and saw where he was staying, and they spent that day with him. It was about four in the afternoon. (John 1:35-39)

We must all by God's grace refuse to settle for anything less than the fullness of life God has **freely gifted** to us in Christ. When John the Baptist told his own disciples to "Behold the Lamb of God who takes away the sins of the world." he was again testifying that he was **not** the Messiah. He was stating clearly and simply, as a servant in God's house that; although he had a distinct honor as the forerunner, the Elijah who was to come, a key witness and servant and the greatest prophet of the era of the people of God under the Old Covenant Law of Moses, Jesus Christ was and IS in spirit and in truth **the embodiment** of the fulness of God's revelation of Himself to all mankind. This is what John and Andrew understood, which is why they from that moment became Jesus' disciples and went with Him and abode with Him. And with each other in Him (John 1). Denominations and divisions of men, the traditions of men are self-serving and self-righteous. They are sinful, full of missing the mark of the fruitfulness of Christlikeness and **life** in us and all who come into contact with Christ in us, our and their only hope of glory.

Knowing and being known by God in His Son; our Adonai/Lord and Savior Jesus was and will always be about being personally and intimately known by Him and each other in Him, in His local Body-life to which we are joined and become living branches and fruitful trees full of and bearing all of the fruit of the Spirit.

> <sup>**1**</sup> There is therefore now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus. <sup>**2**</sup> For the law of the life-giving Spirit in Christ Jesus has set you free from the law of sin and death. <sup>**3**</sup> For God achieved what the law could not do because it was weakened through the flesh. By sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh and concerning sin, he condemned sin in the flesh, <sup>**4**</sup> so that the righteous requirement of the law may be fulfilled in us, who do not walk according to the flesh but according to the Spirit. (Romans 8:1-4)

All self-righteousness is being cut-down and cut off from the Father and the Son. It cannot be otherwise. Remember Ananias and Sapphira. (Acts 5:1-11) Remember also the ones who were sick and the ones who fell asleep at Corinth for partaking of the Lord's **communion** unworthily (1 Corinthians 11:27-30) This too speaks to the ax laid to the root of the trees.

In the entirety of Mathew 23 Our Lord and Head of His Body the Ekklesia/Church, warned the people about experts in the Law of Moses. These same Jewish elders/leaders/trees that John the Baptist had earlier called a brood of vipers are exposed by the light of the truth proclaimed to them by Christ Himself. Those claiming the Law of Moses as their source and supply of wisdom and guidance for teaching others and pleasing the Father is essentially 'sitting in or being taught by those sitting in Moses' seat. They've been neo-Judaized and become stuck and bewitched by sin-consciousness and focusing on their own efforts and prideful zeal to earn salvation. But our salvation is and will always be the **free gift** of God to fallen humanity. Strict adherence to and observance of the letter of the Law will always only produce death because our heritage under the first Adam is sinfulness and death. Mathew's Gospel proclaims the Tree of Life, **not** preoccupation with the tree of the knowledge of good and Evil. Jesus Christ is the Tree of Life all who would live are invited to partake of and feast upon daily. Except you eat my flesh and drink my blood (Communion) you have no part in me. Are we professing Christ, yet not bearing the fruit of the Spirit? Individuals and institutions that constantly resist, reject and grieve the Spirit of Truth, **love**, and Life today have the ax laid to their roots. The Letter kills but the Spirit produces organic and abiding life which means we become as trees planted by the unceasing stream of the water of life. All these lovely images and shadows and types find their fulness and substance in Jesus Christ.

Let's not settle for being neither old-fashioned Judaized nor new-fashioned Judaizing by any sons of the wicked one. Let's simply live lovingly in the reality of Jesus'promise to us that whom He the Son sets free **is** and remains **free** indeed.

John the Baptist stated over 2,000 years ago "even now the Ax is laid to the root". That singular root, friends, is religiosity, that is, old first-Adam-self-centered and old-first-Adam-self absorbed. It can look very respectable and decent just like the Pharisees and Sadducees appeared to be. It can even be very well-meaning and well-intentioned, but the eyes of the Lord still see through and beyond the surface and the superficial.

Let's not cleave to the Law of Moses (this is what being Judaized amounts to. You're stuck in the history and traditions of what was and are not quickened in and to the Life that is in the Holy Spirit... And Jesus is that Spirit, that Second Adam that is the **life-giving** Spirit!!! Hallelujah!!!

This letter of Paul's to the Galatians which I referenced earlier deals most largely with the apostles; Paul and his companions become the Ax of God's Word in this letter to the Galatian assemblies of the Lord's people.

In Chapter 5 Paul is continuing his passionate appeal to those whom the Lord had made him and his missionary companions servants bringing them the Bread of Life. Had these saints allowed themselves to come under the Judaizers' influence completely, they in effect would have made a shipwreck of their faith in Christ. They would have allowed themselves to become bewitched by those who wanted to take pride in their flesh. And the ax would have to have been applied to the root of the trees.

Today there is all manner of Judaizing spirits warring against the Spirit of Truth. But they cannot prevail. There is no end to the increase of the Truths government on Earth as it is in Heaven. To whom is our Heavenly Father's warning going out in this sharing? Certainly, it is His grace and mercies to us all in these trying times. Let us purpose to rest from striving in the flesh and allow His Spirit to wash and purge our consciences from dead works to serve the Living God. Christ in us is still saying come unto me all ye that labor and are heavy laden and I will give you **rest**. Cooperate with me... abide and rest in me by grace through faith and organically I will produce in you, by my Spirit in you, an authentic fruit of repentance and righteousness!

Otherwise, you will be cut off and cut down from the **life** that is in Jesus Christ and His Body the Ekklesia. The entire Chapter 5 of Galatians attest to this. And the witness of Christ Himself again, this time in the Book of The Revelation of Jesus Christ provides an even more sobering (and sumptuous meat) for all who love to feast in our Father's presence to nourish themselves upon the Bread and Wine of the Word. Christ warns us that any leaven of Nicolaitan ideology, Jezebel ideology, Balaam, and Balak ideology is a snare of which believers today need to beware. He warns us to ensure our love for Him and each other in His Body is burning and fiery passion. In Him, we have all we need to ensure we are always bearing the fruit of the Spirit and need never fear being cut down trees for having a form of godliness that denies the power of godliness His **presence** alive and active within us produces daily. He is entirely desirous of and devoted to producing daily Body of Christ incarnate; filled full and fully alive and functional **love-life** in us.

Are we truly seeking first our gracious and loving Heavenly Father's kingdom and righteousness?... is Jesus Christ alive and incarnate in our daily living? Let's not deceive ourselves beloveds. Thank you for posing this question and I pray my sharing is received in the spirit in which it is intended, for the love of the Truth of our God in His Son our Savior and Adonai Jesus/Yeshua. Blessings.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: @WayneCampbellThank you for your contribution. However this answer tends to morph into preaching instead of directly sticking to the point of the question at hand. What is called for is an exegesis of this verse, not a sermon--which would be good in church, though. Perhaps you could study the historical background of John's statement (the pending Destruction of the Temple (Matthew 24:1-3). Peace.